# Setting NaN values for a given set of columns

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image, `img` of dimension 1000 x 500. I want to replace the pixel values of first 248 coulmns and last 58 columns as NaN. What I thought is something like this:

```
img[0: 247,1] = NaN
img[443:499,1] = NaN
```

I get an error like `name 'NaN' is not defined`

Comment: `NaN` does not exist in Python. Go with `None`.

Comment: thanks but when I did this, only 2nd column is replaced with NaN but I want from first to 248th colum.

Comment: what about math.nan or float('nan') depending on your python version?

Comment: Anyway, `NaN` has float properties which `None` doesn't have, more specifically, it can be propagated through operations. `numpy.NaN` is probably the best solution (and actually a good one).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the numpy nan object?

```
import numpy as np
img[0:247,1] = np.nan
```

Comment: This is vastly better than my solution, although I like to think my cautionary remarks still apply. Have an upvote.

Comment: Yep, it's going to be a native solution in most image processing applications.

Comment: thanks but its not working. It onlu replaces the 1st column, other columns are same

Comment: I only copied the line for the first column for your code... your other section would still be indexed by `img[443:499,1] = np.nan`. Anyway isn't it `img[:, 1]` and `img[:, -58:]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
import numpy as np
img[:, 0:247]= np.nan
```